# What is the secure directory to store files in storage in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, filesystems, laravel-filesystem

I'm new to Laravel and I don't know the exact directory I should store my important files in.

is it
"storage/app/myFolder"
or
"storage/myFolder"
?

Do I have to change anything in config/filesystems?
Are there any special security matters?